# Encrypt and Hash AJAX calls for communication with two servers

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, encryption

I have created two sample application

1. ASP.NET WEB API and
2. ASP.NET MVC application

Some of my MVC application screens access WEB API by making AJAX calls, which I was able to implement sucessfully.

Now I would like to implement Hasing/Encryption without using 
HTTPS.

My question is inorder to implement Hasing/Encryption 
for the AJAX calls,do I need to

1. first make an AJAX call to MVC method.
2. Encrypt/Hash the JSON ,
3. Return it to the Browser
4. and then make an AJAX call using Encrypted/Hashed JSON to the WEB API

Is this approach correct ?

Comment: *"I would like to implement Hasing/Encryption without using HTTPS"* I hope you know that this can't be made secure against man-in-the-middle attacks. Also hashing and encryption are two entirely different things. Do you actually mean hashing, encryption or both? What kind of data are you sending and what do you want to protect against?

Comment: Artjom B @ 
1. Would like to implement both Hasing and Encryption
2. Yes , I do understand that "STEP 1" is not secured against
   man-in-the-middle attacks, but my concern is about the AJAX call
   from MVC to WEB API.
3. It's JSON data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the client supposed to be able to decrypt the data returned from the MVC method?

#### No

If not then you can use the same pre-shared secret key in both MVC and Web API and your approach would be relatively secure. You would need to use HMAC instead of a simple hash to verify authenticity of the data. Use a second and different key as the HMAC key.

Run the HMAC over the encrypted data (encrypt-then-MAC) with the second key and send it along with the ciphertext. When the Web API receives the ciphertext and the MAC it should first verify the MAC before attempting to decrypt.

#### Yes

In order to make this at least a little bit secure, you need to use asymmetric encryption for the key exchange of the symmetric key.

Preparation: Generate two RSA (or others) key pairs. One for the MVC endpoint and the other for the Web API. Move the private keys to the server endpoints and add the public keys in encoded form to the client page.

1. Client: generates an AES key, encrypts it with the MVC public key and sends it to the MVC
2. MVC: decrypts encrypted AES with its RSA private key, encrypts the data with the recovered AES key and returns it to the client
3. Client: decrypts the data with its AES key and does something with it
4. Client: encrypts (a part) of the data with the AES key, encrypts the AES key with the public key of the Web API and sends both ciphertexts to the Web API
5. Web API: decrypts the encrypted AES key with its private key, decrypts the data with the AES key, does something with the data and returns some result (possibly encrypted with AES)

In order to make this more robust, you can generate two symmetric keys and use one for encryption and the other for HMAC in order to authenticate the symmetric ciphertexts.

Comment: I would be going with "No" approach , that should solve my purpose , thanks.